# How to install/uninstall with pip to specific python folder?

Tags: python, pip, directory

I have a specific python2.7 folder where I would like to install packages using pip. The default python install is python 2.6

I managed to install numpy with `<python2.7Folder>/pip -t ... numpy`. The problem is that it compiled using the default python 2.6 libs and not it does not work . 
When I try to run numpy from python 2.7 I get this : `undefined symbol: _PyUnicodeUCS4_IsWhitespace ... expectable`.

So I try to uninstall this, but can't do it as it tried to uninstall it from the default python install.

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pip-1.1-py2.6.egg/pip/req.py", line 410, in uninstall
    raise UninstallationError("Cannot uninstall requirement %s, not installed" % (self.name,))
```

The questions are:

- how can I first uninstall the numpy package from a specific folder, from a specific python path.
- How can I reinstall numpy, this itme using a specific path for the python includes ?

Comment: There are two installations of Python, python2.6 as default, and python2.7 in a specific folder. The installation is correctly made for python2.7 lib folder, but during compilation it used python2.6 include folders. What I need is to nos uninstall and use the correct include folder.

Comment: Problem solved. Putting the answer here for all those of you that come here looking for the same answers.

Added python2.7 folder as fist one in the $PATH list.

edited pip file making it point to the expected python binary file (first line of the script)

all good now.

Answer (score 1):

To install libraries under Python2.7 you need the "2.7" version of pip. In other words, pip must be using `python2.7` itself.

You can chech which python version pip is using with this:

```
$ head -1 `which pip`
#!/home/lbolla/.virtualenvs/work/bin/python2
```

Anyway, I strongly recommend you to use [virtualenv](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/index.html), so you'll be able to create a new virtual environment every time you want and you'll not pollute python's system directories with packages.

Finally, you should be able to uninstall packages installed with `pip` using: `pip uninstall <package>`.

Comment: I did install using python 2.7 pip, by using the correct binary, not the default. There must be some option in the install to force a specific python folder location. Removing is not working, as mentioned in the question, as even using the correct python 2.7 pip binary it runs the default, and wrong, python binary

Comment: virtualenv usage might not help. From my understanding of  virtualenv, it creates multiple environments for one python instalation. I have two instances of Python installed in separated folders, and want to install with pip on the non-standard one .

Comment: `pip install --target=DIR` installs to `DIR`.

Answer (score 0):

it is better if you create virtulenv and do everything there.

for example if you want to install numpy for python 2.6 you should do something like this

---

$easy_install-2.6 virtualenv

$virtualenv-2.6 python26

$source python26/bin/activate

$easy_install numpy or $ pip install numpy

---